# IOS/Objective-C/Xcode: implicit conversion loses integer precision error with int

Tags: ios, objective-c, int

When using int to count the elements of an array e.g.:

```
 int size = [latestComments count];
```

which I have been doing in my app, I am getting the compiler warning:

Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

I never worried about this too much because I figured precision was close enough when dealing with integers but I want to get rid of the warnings.  To silence the warnings, is it safe to change all of these to:

```
long size = [latestComments count];
```

This seems to silence the warnings on an ad hoc basis, but I would like to be sure, there are no greater consequences, I'm not aware of.  (I have noticed that changing it to NSInteger or NSUInteger while silencing the warning can cause downstream issues when they are used in comparisons and so forth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` will not solve your problems. The `count` property returns an unsigned integer `NSUInteger`. 
To get rid of the error you'll have to declare `NSUInteger size = ..`.

It might push the warning to where you'll be using `size` since if the types don't match again.

Comment: I frequently use:  int i; int count = [myArray count]; for (i=0;i<count;i++).  Can you compare an int to an NSUInteger?  Alternatively what do you think of explicitly casting it as in int count(int)[self.myArray count];

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue comparing the two. NSUInteger can never be negative so as long as your original int is never negative, it should be pretty seamless.